# Why is this term still standing when checking this solution for a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am being asked to check that, for the differential equation:

$zy''+(z-1)y'-2y=0$

about $z=0$ for $z>0$ is:

$w=k_1y_1+k_2y_2$ with $y_1=z^2$, $y_2=Cy_1\log(z)+\sum_{n=0}b_nz^{n+c_2}$.

The question assumes that $C=1$, $b_2=0$, so $y_2=z^2\log(z)-1+2z-(1/3)z^3+(1/4)z^4+...$

It also says to "check up to those terms" (the ones written for $y_2$ above). Problem is, when I tried doing this, I ended up with a $\frac{k_2z^4}{12}$ term that does not cancel out. Is this because we're checking up to only those terms and therefore approximating?